# Is creating a constant dictionary inside a function efficient in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say, I have a function that creates a dictionary just to look up a value, e.g.:

```
def check_map(val):
   value_map = {"val1": "newval1", "val2": "newval2", "val3": "newval3"}
   val = value_map.get(val, val)
   # other stuff
   return val
```

Will Python optimize the dictionary creation in any way since it's basically a constant?

Comment: "Optimize the dictionary creation" in what "way"?  That is, what is there to optimize?

Comment: If the dictionary is effectively static, then just declare it globally.

Comment: @ScottHunter Not create it from scratch on every call

Comment: CPython doesn't do optimisation of this kind of constant creation. As @CtrlZ mentioned, you can notice this and make this dictionary a global to avoid creating it on every call.

Comment: You could use a [function attribute](https://peps.python.org/pep-0232/) instead of a global or local variable.

Comment: In older versions of (C)Python there used to be significant overhead in accessing a global, compared to a local, but I think that's been optimized in recent versions.

Comment: A function attribute is still a global (or at least non-local) lookup; there's no way to access the function directly, only via a non-local variable you *assume* refers to the same function.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
import dis
dis.dis(check_map)
```

I see **some** optimization in CPython 3.11.4, but a new dict is built every time:

```
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('newval1')
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('newval2')
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 ('newval3')
              8 LOAD_CONST               4 (('val1', 'val2', 'val3'))
             10 BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP      3
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (value_map)

  3          14 ... (rest of the function)
```